# map the UHP to an equilateral triangle

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions, mobius-transformation

Explain how the upper half-plane can be mapped one-to-one and conformally onto an equilateral triangle.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Riemann mapping theorem tells you that such a map exists, but does not provide the actual map. Here you can use a [Schwarz-Christoffel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping) of the form $$S(z)=\int_0^z\frac{d\zeta}{(\zeta-A_1)^{\beta_1}\dots(\zeta-A_n)^{\beta_n}} $$
Can you figure out which parameters $A_1,\dots,A_n$ and $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n$ are suitable?

Comment: Hi @MichaelM, thanks for your post - I am currently reading up on this mapping on Wikipedia now.  I'd much rather solve the problem with a composition of elementary mappings - do you think this is possible?  Or is this a question that has very few (perhaps only one) different ways of solving?  Thanks,

Comment: @LebronJames, notice that Schwarz-Christoffel transformation for triangles generally gives you hypergeometric functions in the end, and they do not reduce to more elementary forms. (Even if you focus on a regular triangle, you end up with elliptic integrals, which are equally unlikely to be cute!) An exception to this situation is when you send one of the vertex to the point at infinity, in which case you end up with a half strip.

Comment: @LebronJames, actually it can be shown that this mapping is essentially unique. That is, if $F$ is a conformal map from $\mathbb{H}$ to a simple polygon $P$, then $F(z)=c_{1}S(z)+c_2$ for an appropriate Schwarz-Christoffel integral $S(z)$ and constants $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{C}$ (Stein-Shakarchi, p. 241). If you'd like some motivation for the Schwarz-Christoffel formula, note that a conformal map $F:\mathbb{H}\to P$ must take the real line to the boundary of $P$, and consider its derivative on the real line.

Comment: Hi @MichaelM., I just edited my post, after studying Jacobi's "elliptic integral of the first kind".  Perhaps I am close now.  What do you think?  I still need to make some modifications to the integral, but I welcome any suggestions you may have :-)  Thanks,

Comment: Hi @SangchulLee, I edited my post to include my work, after studying elliptic integrals today - what do you think of it?  Feel free to offer any hints  or suggestions.  Thanks :-)

Comment: You might want either two or three branch points, depending on whether the point at $\infty$ is mapped to one of the triangle vertices. Also, think about how you might change the "turning" angle from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{3}$ (hint: the polygon angles depend on the parameters $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n$).

Comment: Hi @MichaelM., I just posted my answer as an edit to my original question - what do you think?  I feel I am close to the correct answer... thanks,

Comment: Looks like you are close - the problem you have now is that the integrand is essentially $w^{-\frac{2}{3}}$ for large $w$, so the integral does not converge at $\infty$. Can you fix it? (Also, the angle change at the two finite branch points is not quite what you want.)

Comment: Hmmm...how about now, @MichaelM.?  (i) I removed the square root, (ii) I changed the powers to be -1/3, and (iii) I added a $w^2$ factor to help with the convergence of the integral.  :-)

Comment: I just realized that adding the factor of $w^2$ makes z=0 a branch point, @michaelm. ...

Comment: That still isn't the right angle, the angle at branch point $k$ is $\pi(1-\beta_k)$.

Comment: Hi @MichaelM., but then that would give $e^{\frac{i2\pi}{3}}$, which I feel like implies that the integrand will turn 120 degrees instead of the required 60 degrees, as x crosses the branch points from left to right.  Don't we want $e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}$?  Thanks,

Comment: Hi @MichaelM., basically, my thinking is that, as we cross a branch point from left to right, one of the two factors gets a sign change, so we pick up a factor of -1 = $e^{i\pi}$, so ...at that moment, if my exponents were 1/3, I'd get a factor of  $e^{{i\pi}/3}$, which rotates the integrand 60 degrees counterclockwise ...to trace out an equilateral triangle...

Comment: Hi @MichaelM., so, it turns out that the exponents correspond to *exterior* angles of the image polygon - but why?  The integrand should clearly turn at an angle of 60 degrees = the interior angle, in order to trace out an equilateral triangle... thanks,

Comment: Ahhh...I'm looking at a nice picture now - I think I got it!  :-)  at least the exponents.  So, my denominator is just (w+1)^(2/3) (w-1)^(2/3) , @MichaelM. And the integral is small like w^(-4/3), so the integral converges, too.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: [Riemann mapping theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem)

Comment: This would be a fine Comment, but I think it lacks the concrete aspects that the Question's details seem to call for.  OTOH, the OP specifies "hints only", so it might be what was hoped for.

Comment: Hi @hardmath and / or Spenser:  MichaelM's hint above is a great one, but I wonder if this question is one where the answer is pretty much of the type, "if you don't know this fancy Schwarz-Christoffel mapping, you're screwed."  or...is there a way to solve this question with a composition of the elementary mappings, e.g., mobius transformations, $e^z$, $z^\alpha$?  If there is indeed another way, I would love to hear your suggestions.  Thanks,